# terraform need subnets ids from private and public subnet for nacl association

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, subnet

We have a requirement to use subnets in private and public to be associated in terraform nacl.

How to get id of two subnets ?

```
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  subnet_ids = aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id
  egress {
    protocol   = "tcp"
    rule_no    = 200
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "10.3.0.0/18"
    from_port  = 443
    to_port    = 443
  }
```

Similiarly need to fetch for private subnet.

aws_subnet.private_subnet.*.id

how to get both private and public subnet together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/concat.html) the ids:

```
locals {
 all_subnet_ids = concat(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, aws_subnet.private_subnet.*.id)
}
```